# ‘gameRunning’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, linux, conditional-statements

```
bool gamerunning = true;
while (gamerunning)
         while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            gameRunning = false;
```

This is what I'm doing and on the 5th line I get this error:

> ‘gameRunning’ was not declared in this scope

Anyone know the problem?

Comment: C++ is case sensitive, change gameRunning to gamerunning on your 5th line.

Comment: @Daniel, make it an answer :)

Comment: oh my god cant believe i made such a stupid mistake!!

Comment: @Skurmedel: I'm sure you knew the answer, go ahead and post it! I don't want to taint my answers with answers pointing out typo mistakes :D OCD alert.

Comment: @Daniel, nah, I was busy fixing the formatting :)

Comment: @amin: We all do :) I've spent 2 hours looking for a missing semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

This will fix the error:

```
bool gamerunning = true; 

while (gamerunning)
{
  while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
  {
    if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
    {
      gamerunning = false;  // <--- fixed spelling
    }
  }
}
```

The braces are not necessary for the compiler. But it improves readibility espacially if you have several control flow statements in line. The only *bug* was the capital R in `gamerunning`.